# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'noticeNo') React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'noticeNo') React.js

Error occurred after adding const "item"

How to fix this error?

I've tried a lot of things with my search, but it doesn't work

I try

```
  const item = noticeDatas && sortedItems[0];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (noticeDatas) {
      getData();
    }
  }, []);
```

and this is my code

```
export const HomeNotice = () => {
  const [noticeDatas, setNoticeDatas] = useState([] as Array<NoticeDataModel>);

  const sortedItems = noticeDatas.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
    a.regDateTime < b.regDateTime ? 1 : b.regDateTime < a.regDateTime ? -1 : 0
  );

  const item = sortedItems[0];

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Notice</h3>
      <Link to={"help/notice/" + Number(item.noticeNo)}>
        <div>
          <span>{parse(item.title)}</span>
          <span>{item.regDateTime}</span>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </>
  );

  async function getData() {
    let noticeDataList: Array<NoticeDataModel> =
      await NoticeDataService.getAll();
    setNoticeDatas(noticeDataList);
  }
};
```

Comment: `<Link to={"help/notice/" + Number(item?.noticeNo)}>` try this? Put the question mark after item. Is this where you are getting the error?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but there was another error. Uncaught TypeError: First argument must be a string

Comment: `item` is undefined, you need to make sure it is not undefined or handle it by displaying something else that is not dependent on `item`

Comment: I found that the reason maybe why this error occurred was due to the "parse(html-react-parser)" package. I removed "parse" and the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this

```
const [noticeDatas, setNoticeDatas] = useState([] as Array<NoticeDataModel>);
```

you will notice that you set empty array as initial state for `noticeDatas`, meaning that until you fetch data and update state this list will be still empty, and when you do this on empty list

```
const item = sortedItems[0]; // This will be `undefined` initially, until you get data
...
...
Number(item.noticeNo); // Meaning that this will resolve to `undefined.noticeNo` - throwing you that exception
```

And you basically end up trying to read attribute on undefined object.

You just need to check if it exist before trying to access any property, for example:

```
const noticeLink = item ? "help/notice/" + Number(item.noticeNo) : null;
...
<Link to={noticeLink}>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that item is initially undefined because noticeDatas is an initially empty array so you need to check if item is undefined before accessing noticeNo by adding a question mark before the dot, like this:

```
item?.noticeNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set an initial value to avoid this bug.
It means to write `Number(item.noticeNo || 0)` in this way.